# Simplify boolean algebra expression

Tags: math, boolean, expression, algebra

Starting from a truth table of one subtractor with three inputs and two outputs I've obtained the following boolean formula for the second output z2 (the "loan" of the bit to the left) :

**z2** = *x0'x1'x2 + x0'x1x2' + x0'x1x2 + x0x1x2*

(where *x0'* means *NOT x0*).

Simplifying it : **z2** = *x2(x0 ⊕ x1)' + x1(x0 ⊕ x2)' + x1x2*

which means : **z2** = *x2(x0 XNOR x1) + x1(x0 XNOR x2) + x1x2*

Can I simplify more?
I've tried with **z2** = (x0 XNOR x1) + (x0 XNOR x2) + x1x2 but it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "simplify." Do you want the fewest possible operations or variable look-ups (treating two occurrences of the same variable as two) or something else? Which operations are allowed?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes I'm just wondering if there's some properties of the boolean algebra which I'm missing to reduce the expression, reducing its operations. Basically, a reduced version in terms of operations which even calculate the same truth table : [link](https://i.gyazo.com/782a67a0e5b7971ca8ef19dbb06349c3.png) , hope I'm clear

Comment: You answered my first question (you want minimal number of operations) but not my second. Which operations are allowed? For unary, complement (NOT)? For binary, AND, OR, NAND, NOR, XOR, implication either direction, others? Any ternary operators?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I've no restrictions in terms of operations, any unary and binary operations are allowed to me, the main goal is just to have a "smarter" version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original expression has 12 variable references and 16 operators. Your simplification has 8 variable references and 7 operators. Here is an expression with 6 variable references and 6 operators:

> **z2** = x0x1x2 + x0'(x1+x2)

I do not know if that is minimal in any sense.

---

You ask how I found that expression. I did not start from your simplification, I started from the truth table that you referenced in a comment. I reproduce it here:

[image: Truth table for original expression]

As I looked the table looking for patterns, I saw that it looks like a chiasm or skew-symmetric matrix: if I flip the last column upside-down then take the complements of all items I end up with the original column. (I don't know the proper term for this kind of symmetry; those are the terms that came to my mind.) I tried to encapsulate that symmetry into a logical expression but failed.

That led me to look at the upper and lower halves of that last column. The upper half is mostly ones and the lower half is mostly zeros. Then it struck me that the upper half looks like the truth table for the binary OR operation and the lower half looks like the binary AND operation. The upper half is for x0' and the lower half is for x0, of course. Putting those facts together gave me my expression.

I confirmed that expression by seeing if I could manipulate the original expression into mine. I could, by doing

```
z2 = x0'x1'x2 + x0'x1x2' + x0'x1x2 + x0x1x2
   = x0'(x1'x2 + x1x2' + x1x2) + x0x1x2
   = x0'(x1 + x2) + x0x1x2
   = x0x1x2 + x0'(x1 + x2)
```

The transition from the second to third line is, of course, equivalent to recognizing the truth table for binary OR, so this is not much different from my actual discovery method.

That latter method may be more transferable to other problems: factor out a common factor from multiple terms. My actual method was more fun but less transferable. My favorite definition of mathematics is "the study of patterns" which explains why the method was fun.

Comment: Could you show me how you ended up with it? Especially how you removed the XNOR operations, I wasn't able to get rid off them.

Comment: Great method and useful explanation, didn't noticed it, I agree about math patterns, they are a constant which I'm rarely able to grasp. Thanks you!